# show json complex string in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, ng-grid

I have a web service which builds a JSON string like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return "[" + string.Join(",", v.getProbingJobs().Select(a => j.Serialize(a)).ToArray()) + "]";
```

(getProbingJobs is an entity framework function retrieving data from a stored procedure)

This Web Service is consumed via AngularJS ($http.get method). I want to display the JSON string in ng-grid in columns . instead it shows ng-grid with one column and each row (cell) shows a char from the JSON string.

My JSON string is built like this:

```
"[{\"visualid\":\"35422064B1181\",\"operator\":\"ishashua\",\"Step\":\"Probe\",\"Eqiument\":\"LTM3538\",\"Last_Step_Start_Time\":\"\\\/Date(1406725260000)\\\/\",\"Job_Name\":\"P0 minVcc (UNIT 35422064B1181 )\",\"Event_Type\":\"\",\"Event_Name\":\"\",\"Job_Status\":\"WIP\",\"Step_Status\":\"Step Closed\",\"Job_Pass_Fail\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Category\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Name\":\"\"},{\"visualid\":\"3E408261B00670\",\"operator\":\"mfridma1\",\"Step\":\"Event\",\"Eqiument\":\"ES4003\",\"Last_Step_Start_Time\":\"\\\/Date(1406732400000)\\\/\",\"Job_Name\":\"minVcc post BI (UNIT 0670)\",\"Event_Type\":\"11 Other\",\"Event_Name\":\"07 Unit Cracked\",\"Job_Status\":\"WIP\",\"Step_Status\":\"Step Closed\",\"Job_Pass_Fail\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Category\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Name\":\"\"},{\"visualid\":\"3E408261B00670\",\"operator\":\"mfridma1\",\"Step\":\"Probe\",\"Eqiument\":\"ES4003\",\"Last_Step_Start_Time\":\"\\\/Date(1406732400000)\\\/\",\"Job_Name\":\"minVcc post BI (UNIT 0670)\",\"Event_Type\":\"\",\"Event_Name\":\"\",\"Job_Status\":\"WIP\",\"Step_Status\":\"Step Started\",\"Job_Pass_Fail\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Category\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Name\":\"\"},{\"visualid\":\"3E408261B00670\",\"operator\":\"mfridma1\",\"Step\":\"Probe\",\"Eqiument\":\"ES4003\",\"Last_Step_Start_Time\":\"\\\/Date(1406732400000)\\\/\",\"Job_Name\":\"minVcc post BI (UNIT 0670)\",\"Event_Type\":\"11 Other\",\"Event_Name\":\"07 Unit Cracked\",\"Job_Status\":\"WIP\",\"Step_Status\":\"Step Started\",\"Job_Pass_Fail\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Category\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Name\":\"\"},{\"visualid\":\"3E408261B00931\",\"operator\":\"kgitelmk\",\"Step\":\"Probing\",\"Eqiument\":\"LVX503\",\"Last_Step_Start_Time\":\"\\\/Date(1406698980000)\\\/\",\"Job_Name\":\"minVcc post BI (UNIT 0931)\",\"Event_Type\":\"\",\"Event_Name\":\"\",\"Job_Status\":\"WIP\",\"Step_Status\":\"Step Started\",\"Job_Pass_Fail\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Category\":\"\",\"Job_Success_Indicator_Name\":\"\"}]"
```

Comment: I think the data you are getting is escaped json as string. In the $http get callback try `JSON.parse(data)` or `angular.fromJson(data)` before assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general @Chandermanis comment is right. But you also have the `Last_Step_Start_Time` field which contains the `DATE()` function and will not be resolved.

You can fix this by using a `CellTemplate` in the `ColumnDefs` and use a custom filter:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | resolve_date}}</div>'
```

Here is the filter (can surely be done more elegant):

```
app.filter('resolve_date', function() {
  return function(text, length, end) {
    text = text.substring(6, 19);
    return Date(text);
  };
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzKk6q?p=preview)

Plz vote @Chandermanis comment up, because this was basically the right answer.

**Update:**

Regarding the width/wrapping issue:

That is a bit complicated to achieve because ng-grid is not a table but a lot of divs displayed as a grid.

First you hat to set the `rowHeight` in the `gridOptions` to a decent value.

Then you have to give each column an individual width so it can display the longest full word.

Last you have to override the css for `ngCellText` like this:

```
.ngCellText.ng-scope{
  white-space:normal;
}
```

Here is an updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pis9XYvXrLL3Ixve7C5d?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. and how do i make the columns width to be automatically (wrap the text and make a max value for column width)? and how do i add horizontal/vertical scroll bars?

Comment: also , the date function returns the current date and not the date of myData. also when i click a cell or scroll than all date values are changes

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ is not reachable at the moment from workplace, so I can't work on this for the moment. But it would be helpful to tell me what kind of timestamp is in Last_Step_Start_Time because a normal unix-timestamp didn't seem to resolve properly. But basically you just have to improve the filter I gave you. I'll be back later...

Comment: thanks. i solved it . but i can't solve the issue with column widths

Comment: OK thanks. Is there an option to make the columns resizable? and add a horizontal slider on the ngGrid ? and a ToolTip that will be shown on mouse over a cell and display the Cell text ?

Comment: Yes, there are many. But since 'm on my weekend and this shouldn't become an individual thread, I recommend you mark this answer as resolved and start a new Question (better two for scrolling and tooltip) and I will have a look at it on monday. Use the plunker with your fixes as a base and a lot more people will come to your aid. Have a nice weekend!